# In MongoDB query, how to get a field in _id included nested document

Tags: mongodb

Assume one document in `student` collection as follows:

```
{
  _id:{
       time: 1
       loc: 'A'
      },
 name: 'Jery'
}
```

I want to filter `_id.time`, like so:

`db.student.find({}, {'_id.time':1})`

But I got a result:

```
{
 _id:{
      time: 1
      loc: 'A'
     }
}
```

Why the result is not as follows:

```
{
 _id:{
      time: 1
     }
}
```

So, where is my error? And how to write the query operation.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe wrong document? Look like you have `time: "1 loc: 'A'"` rather than `time: 1, loc: "A"`

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure the document is right.

Comment: Well, at least the given sample is not valid document.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I simplified it, but the structure of `key-value` pairs is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried a few things but it seems to be a limitation:

```js
> db.students.find({}, {'_id':0, '_id.time': 1})
{  }
{  }
```

```js
> db.students.find({}, {'_id.loc':0, '_id.time': 1})
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

You can however easily achieve this with an aggregation query with a `$project` stage.

```js
> db.students.aggregate( { $project: { '_id.time':1 } } )
{ "_id" : { "time" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : { "time" : 2 } }
```

Comment: But I have a puzzle. Assume the document in the `students1` collection as follows, `{ _id: 0, name:{firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'Brown'}}`. By `db.students1.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'name.lastName':1})` can get the result what I want. such as, `{name:{lastName: 'Brown'}}`. I guess the difference between the two query may be caused by that the `_id` is primary key. Do you think so?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with `_id` is included by default, and you have to explicitly say you don't want it projecting.